# Error while installing X-Pack Plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

I have installed X-Pack in Elasticsearch (ELK stack).X-pack got installed successfully but while starting the Elasticsearch server I am getting following error:

```
[ERROR][o.e.x.w.t.a.g.TransportGetWatchAction] [vBqSs5v] failed to get watch 
[InyQUGAfRNWYflxqFRG7dQ_logstash_version_mismatch]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: watch store not started
```

I have referred following link to install x-pack:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.2/installing-xpack.html#installing-xpack

Unable to resolve this issue.Please guide if someone have any idea about this.